# Rsync all files (recursively) from one dir to another, maintaining only a portion of the original dir structure

Tags: gruntjs, rsync

I have two directories:

**Directory #1, 'C'**

C's absolute path:

```
/A/B/C
```

**Directory #2, 'T'**

T's absolute path:

```
/Q/R/T
```

I want to use **rsync**, to copy all files, recursively, from **C**, and copy them in to **T**, while **maintaining the original directory structure** - *but **only from B onwards**.*

Example to make it clearer: suppose 'B' has only 3 files nested within it:

```
/A/B/f1.txt

/A/B/C/f2.txt

/A/B/C/D/f3.txt
```

Then I want to end up with only f2.txt and f3.txt being copied over, with the final filepaths as follows (notice how I keep the directory structure, only from B onwards):

```
/Q/R/T/B/C/f2.txt

/Q/R/T/B/C/D/f3.txt
```

Here is the catch: **I must execute the rsync cmd from within /Q/R/**.  So when I execute this command, my pwd must be /Q/R/.

Can anyone help me figure out how to do this?

[If I did not have this constraint of where my cwd must be, I could cd to /A/B, and then execute: `rsync . /Q/R/T/ --recursive --relative` .   Unfortunately, I can not do that for reasons that would take a lot of pointless explaining here.   And when I try to execute `rsync /A/. /Q/R/T/ --recursive --relative`, I end up with not only everything within A, but maintaining that first part of the dir structure (/A/) that I don't want.  (Note - in the real life scenario the dir structure is much more complex then this, this is just the general problem.]

Answer (score 2):

The [rsync](https://ss64.com/bash/rsync.html) command includes a couple of options which are suitable for this scenario. They are:

> **`--include=PATTERN`** - *Don't exclude files matching PATTERN*
>
> **`--exclude=PATTERN`** - *Exclude files matching PATTERN*

An excellent description and examples of the `--exclude` flag can be found [here](https://ss64.com/bash/rsync.html#exclude).

---

### Solution

Given the directory structures provided in your question and your `pwd` being set to `/Q/R/`. Running the following command will meet your requirement:

`rsync ../../A/ T/ --recursive --include A/B/** --exclude B/*.*`

**Edit:**

If you do want `/A/B/f1.txt` to copy to `/Q/R/T/B/f1.txt` *(as it's unclear in your question because you don't show it in the "I want to end up with" example"*). Then omit the `--exclude B/*.*` part, so the complete command is reduced to:

`rsync ../../A/ T/ --recursive --include A/B/**`

or reduced even further in complexity to just:

`rsync ../../A/** T/ --recursive`

---

### Explanation of the command

**`../../A/`**

The first argument provides the path to the *source* directory. I.e. The relative position within the hierarchical tree of names *(Based on your `pwd` being `/Q/R`)*.

**`T/`**

The second argument provides the path to the *destination* directory. Again this is a relative position within the hierarchical tree of names *(and is also based on the `pwd` being `/Q/R`)*.

**`--recursive`**

The first option is to recurse into the directories.

**`--include A/B/**`**

This says that you want to *include* all the assets (files/folders), however many levels deep, from within the folder named `B` which resides inside folder `A`.

**`--exclude B/*.*`**

This says that you want to *exclude* any assets (files/folders), whose name includes a dot [`.`] plus extension, which reside inside folder `B` *(at the top level)*. This will prevent the file named `f1.txt` from being copied. You could be even more specific here and use `--exclude B/f1.txt` instead, however I'm assuming in real life you perhaps have additional files you want to exclude here too.

---

### Additional notes

Both the `--include` and `--exclude` options can be utilized multiple times. This can be very useful for some scenarios too as it enables you to be specific about what to include and/or exclude during the copy process.

For example, lets assume that your source directory `/A/B/`, *(as described in your question)*, also contains a folder named `X`. So its path is `A/B/X`.

Lets say that we also do not want to copy this folder named `X` *(in the same way as you currently do not want to copy `/A/B/f1.txt`)*.

For this scenario we add another `--exclude` option as follows:

`rsync ../../A/ T/ --recursive --include A/B/** --exclude B/*.* --exclude X/`

*Note the additional `--exclude X/` at the end.*

You mention...

> (Note - in the real life scenario the dir structure is much more complex then this, this is just the general problem.

... in your question, so you may find it necessary to add additional **`--exclude=PATTERN`** to truly meet your requirements.

---

### Grunt

As you have included the `gruntjs` flag with your question, then you may want to consider utilizing plug-ins which can run shell commands like `rsync` such as:

- [grunt-shell](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-shell)
- [grunt-exec](https://github.com/jharding/grunt-exec)

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Unfortunately this does not seem to work for me.  I think the --exclude, while it does exclude the B level files, also discards the dirs there, and so is skipping over C.  I think I might have worded the question confusing - the real conundrum is to do with paths - to retain the original dir structure from the src, but only beginning at a certain depth.  So in the example, if there is file /A/B/C/D/E/somefile.txt, after rsync, it's final filepath should be /Q/R/T/B/C/D/E/somefile.txt .  I'll play with the command some more, I might be doing your example incorrectly

Comment: It's difficult to tell exactly what your requirement is. You mention _"the real conundrum is to do with paths - to retain the original dir structure from the src, but only beginning at a certain depth"_. In which case it may be you just want: `rsync ../../A/B T/ --recursive --exclude B/*.*` _(which will also exclude `f1.txt`)_ or `rsync ../../A/B T/ --recursive` _(i.e. without the `--exclude B/*.*`to include `f1.txt`)_.